# Looking for C02 cartridge specifications, for 16g and 32g canisters. Looking to find some for deployment use both in both Australia and USA

Tags: payload-deployment, gasses

I am looking for C02 canister specifications, for 16g and 32g cartridges. Looking to find some for deployment use both in both Australia and USA.

We have brought many 16g and 32 g cartridges, but are unsure if they are the same ones as those in America. We also failed to find any product specifications of 16 and 32g canisters, does anyone have a link to them?

This is my first post so please give me feedback as well on what I need to include in my next post, thank you!

Comment: I do not see how this has to do with space travel.

Comment: I am using the canisters to fill a deployment system for a rocket.

Comment: Please edit your post to clearly show its relevance here.

Comment: I would ask somewhere that people use a lot of small CO2 cartridges, like in the airsoft or paintball community. Beyond that, is there a reason you can't simply purchase them and test them or contact the manufacturer for specifications?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Doesn't have the rocket in (the) question be able to reach space for the Rocketman to have the right to ask this question here ?

Comment: @Cornelis [model-rocketry] is on topic here as long as you're not trying to blow yourself up.